# Unable to access server using ssh after setting a static ip in alpine Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking, dhcp, alpine

I am trying to configure a new Alpine server, and I have some basic knowledge of networking & Linux only.

Everything works seamlessly if I use the default configs with DHCP, but breaks when I try to use a static IP config.
I have to configure adguard home and a few apps on this system, every day

By default, the network config with DHCP gives a dynamic IP like `192.168.68.110`

I changed the config using `nano /etc/network/interfaces` and below are my config samples:

Default config had:

```
auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

My new config is:

```
auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.10.1
  netmask 255.255.0.0
  gateway 192.168.29.1
```

If I do an ifconfig I get the below:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXX
          inet addr:192.168.10.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e65f:1ff:fe31:9e45/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3826 errors:0 dropped:87 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:367860 (359.2 KiB)  TX bytes:516 (516.0 B)
```

The output for `ip addr` is

```
inet 192.168.10.1/24 scope global eth0        
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But I am even not able to ping the machine with a new config from `192.168.68.103` machine.

Comment: What is your goal with the static address configuration? What does the dhcp-provided configuration look like? In addition to the output of `ip addr` (which you should be using instead if `ifconfig`), also include the output of `ip route`. Does your system have multiple interfaces? Your gateway needs to be on the same network as your one of your interfaces. Given your netmask for `eth0`, we would expect your gateway to be `192.168.10.<something>`.

Comment: What is the network topology, that is, how are the server, router and client machine connected?

Comment: The IP is changing frequently and I have to configure adguard home and a few apps on this system, every day I try to ssh I find a new ip on this. 
I am using tp link deco router which is my secondary gateway on `192.168.68.1` having dhcp enabled, the primary gateway is `192.168.29.1` which is my ISP-provided router.
All my devices are connected to the deco router after a switch in a star topology

Comment: the output for `ip addr` is `inet 192.168.10.1/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: The subnet mask in your ´ip addr´ output is wrong. It shows a class C (255.255.255.0) where it should be a class B (255.255.0.0). Check your config again.

Answer (score 1):

The netmask in the ip config output is still a /24 subnetmask.
Please verify that. Maybe you need to reboot.
Please check the routing as well

`ip route`